# virtualbox running on Mac OS X: how to emulate Alt-F4?

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox

I have a Windows virtual host running under Mac OS X. I found how to emulate the Windows key (using the right Command key) but couldn't find how to close windows using keyboard shortcut; under a normal Windows host I just press Alt-F4 but I don't know how to generate this keyboard combination with my Macbook keyboard.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function keys are set-up normaly just press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That key combination worked (with the exception of the command window, it doesn't close with that key combination)